# my grub is not show my win 8 along with kali linux

Tags: windows-8, multi-boot, grub, kali-linux

i install kali in my windows 8 PC but it don't show my windows in my grub
I tried to update the grub but it don't work and neither it shows grub2

Comment: What doesn't work when you try to update grub, and what doesn't show grub2?